# How to measure the speed for tc (traffic control) in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tc

I have the following settings:

```
tc qdisc del dev $ETH0ORSIMILAR root
tc qdisc add dev $ETH0ORSIMILAR root handle 1: htb default 30
tc class add dev $ETH0ORSIMILAR parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps
tc class add dev $ETH0ORSIMILAR parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 5kbps
tc qdisc add dev $ETH0ORSIMILAR parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10
```

What is 5kbps? Is it KiloBit per second or KiloBytes per second?

Unless I'm completely mistaken, an scp test shows me in average `294.6KB/s`-`500KB/s` for `5kbps` setting above.

I'm a bit confused how this works out.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) has a Units section which suggests that kbps is Kilobytes per second.

Remember this about the htb

> HTB ensures that **the amount of service provided to each class is at least the minimum of the amount it requests and the amount assigned to it**. When a class requests less than the amount assigned, the remaining (excess) bandwidth is distributed to other classes which request service.

You are guaranteeing 5kbps to calss 1:30 but if there is spare capacity it can use up to 100mbps.

```
Units
Bandwidths or rates can be specified in:
kbps
Kilobytes per second

mbps
Megabytes per second

kbit
Kilobits per second

mbit
Megabits per second

bps or a bare number
Bytes per second
Amounts of data can be specified in:
kb or k
Kilobytes
mb or m
Megabytes
mbit
Megabits

kbit
Kilobits

b or a bare number
Bytes.
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Now I understand what is happening. In my example above, if I changed `100mbps` to `5kbps`, then I would ensure that every connection gets truly `5kbps` and it won't be able to burst above it? Or will it rather cause a side effect that HTB believes the maximum capacity it has available is only 5 kbps and the next user gets 0 kbps, because there is nothing left?

Comment: They are easy experiments to perform and doing so will be of great advantage to you..

Comment: Indeed. If I did two `scp` processes from the same client to the server and each would upload a large file. This would count as two separate connections, which can help to test the scenario above, correct?